# Show single data against 3 ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have 40 employees and their annual gross revenue.  I need a single bar with 3 ranges/colors.  The top of the bar needs to be green and the range is > $20000.  The middle of the bar needs to be yellow and the range is $15000 - $19999.  The bottom of the bar needs to be red and the range is < $14999.  Then I need a black, horizontal line or tick mark or something across the bar with the individual driver's data.  The goal is to show where they sit against company standards of good, ok and poor.  Please help!!

Teylyn: That is exactly what I need! I apologize, I'm having difficulty adding images but what you've shown is precisely what I need. The scatter chart is the part I was missing. When trying to add the scatter chart I add the data (in your example Bella and 17556), it adds a stack on top of that amount. When I try to change series chart type to Scatter with Smooth Lines the entire chart goes blank. What am I doing wrong?  Can you clarify a little bit about the error bar?  I'm not familiar with that.  Thanks!

Comment: I don’t quite understand.  Can you try to explain in other words?  It would help if you could provide sample data (not *real* data; make up some names and numbers) and an illustration of the chart you want. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this screenshot:
[image]

The chart is a combination of stacked column and scatter chart. The three values for the stacked column are in rows 2 - 4.

The value for the XY Scatter series is in B7 (for Y, the X value is fixed as 1 in the chart source dialog). The Scatter series point has an error bar with the settings both, no cap, fixed value at 0.3.

Cell A7 has a data validation drop-down. Cell B7 looks up the value for the selected person from the data table. The black bar will then move its position.

**Edit:** Some more details on how to go about the black bar:

- select the cell B7 and copy it
- click the chart, then click Home ribbon > Paste > Paste special
- in the Paste Special dialog make sure to select "New Series". Leave the rest as is.
- this will stack the value as a new data series on top of the column
- on the Chart Tools Design ribbon select **Change Chart Type**
- Select **Combo** and make sure the red, yellow and green series are Clustered Column. Set the remaining series to Scatter
- Depending on the value and the color of the new series, it may be very difficult to see and click, so ...
- on the Chart Tools Format ribbon, select the new series with the drop-down at the very left of the ribbon
- Temporarily format the series to have a big blue marker that is easy to click
- With the new series selected, click the + next to the chart, then Error Bars > More Options
- Delete the vertical error bar and format the remaining horizontal error bar to have Direction = Both, End Style = no Cap, fixed value = 0.3
- format the line of the error bar to have a width of 3 pt
- now select the marker again and format it to no fill and no line to make it invisible. That leaves just the error bar.

Comment: I added some steps for the Scatter series and the error bar.